# mv command problem

Tags: command-line, permissions, icons, themes, mv

I try to use the `mv` command, but it throws an error like this:

```
adi@LMToshi2 ~ $ mv ~/compass-icon-theme /usr/share/icons
mv: cannot move '/home/adi/compass-icon-theme' to '/usr/share/icons/compass-icon-theme': Permission denied
adi@LMToshi2 ~ $
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason of the error is that you are running as `non root` user and trying to move a folder into a system folder, which is owned by `root`

The following command should work:

```
sudo mv ~/compass-icon-theme /usr/share/icons
```

> Note: Before running a command as `root` by using `sudo` - Please double check that you know what the command do, and that you do want to execute it.